# K degree regular graph of n vertex

Tags: graph-theory

I am pretty new in descrete math and graph theory.
I have problems to answer this question:

1. Is it possible to have k degree regular graph of n vertex?
   And the other one:
2. What is the maximum degree regular not connected graph of n vertex?

For the first one, I think the answer is no, because either the degree should be even, but is this right and how to prove it?
For the second one I have problems to calculate it because the graph is disconnected (not every vertex should be connected to every other vertex)

Thanks for explanations

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you're on the right track. How many edges does the first graph have?

Your second question is not the correct translation of the second problem you were given. The correct translation is "What is the maximum possible degree an *incomplete* regular graph on 27 vertices can have?" For a complete proof, you need to state the maximum possible degree, then provide an example of such a graph with that degree, and also prove that no higher degree is possible.

Comment: @OP Yes, I've seen that. Your first question is the correct translation of your first problem into graph theory. I've addressed your second question already.